# Django Models are not created in DB after running migration

Tags: python, django-models

I want to fetch data from an API and store it in DB. But the api url should not be hardcoded in view. So I have created api.py in which calling the url request as below:

```
class API(object):
def __init__(self, key, base_url=None):
    self._key = key
    self._base_url = base_url
def get_predictor(self):
    payload = {'key': self._key, 'results':'100'}
    response = requests.get(
    self._get_url(),
    data=payload,
    timeout=(3.1, 10))
    self._get_url_predictor()
def _get_url_predictor(self):
    return '/'.join([self._base_url, 'api', 'meter', 'feed.json'])
```

Then I have created a file predictor were I am passing parameter to url and fetching details from API as below:

```
import urllib,json
from django.conf import settings
from AppSerializer.models import EnergyOTAPI, PowerPrediction
from AppSerializer.meter.api import API
def update_api_predictor():
for meter in EnergyOTAPI.objects.all():
            get_api_predector_data(meter)
def get_api_predector_data(meter):
api = API (
    key=meter.key,
    base_url=settings.SOURCE_ENDPOINTS['url_api'][0]
)
endpoint = api.get_predictor()
serialized_data = urllib.request.urlopen(endpoint).read()
output = json.loads(serialized_data)
def _create_sp_power_prediction_from_api():
    created_at = output['channels'][0]['feeds'][0]['created_at']
    entry_id = output['channels'][0]['feeds'][0]['entry_id']
    value = output['channels'][0]['feeds'][0]['value']
    PowerPrediction.objects.create(created=created_at,
                                        entry=entry_id,
                                        value=value)
```

Then for those fields I created models, serializer, views and url as below.

MOdels:

```
from django.db import models
class EnergyOTAPI:
key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
class PowerPrediction:
created = models.DateField()
entry = models.IntegerField('max_length=500')
value = models.IntegerField('max_length=500')
```

Serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from AppSerializer.models import PowerPrediction

class PowerPredictonSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    source = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='source.pk')
    class Meta:
        model = PowerPrediction
        fields = ('created',
                  'entry',
                  'value')
```

Views:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import generics, permissions, viewsets
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework.response import Response
from AppSerializer.models import PowerPrediction
from AppSerializer.serializer import PowerPredictonSerializer

@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
return Response({
    'locations': reverse('solar:location-list', request=request,      format=format),
 'sources': reverse('source-list', request=request, format=format)
})

class PowerPredictionList(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset = PowerPrediction.objects.all()
serializer_class = PowerPredictonSerializer
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(location=self.request.location)

class PowerPredictionDetail(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
queryset = PowerPrediction.objects.all()
serializer_class = PowerPredictonSerializer
```

Comment: Please clean up your indentation. It makes it very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Your models do not extend the Django `django.db.models.Model` class.

You import `models` from `django.db` at the top of your models file, so you just need to change your `models.py` file as follows:

```
class EnergyOTAPI(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class PowerPrediction(models.Model):
    created = models.DateField()
    entry = models.IntegerField('max_length=500')
    value = models.IntegerField('max_length=500')
```